# How to use polkadot{.js} substrate methods in itraction with kusama's gov2

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, substrate-front-end, gov2

Until now, to follow the referendums through the polkadot.js api, I was using storage methods that are part of the default Substrate runtime (located here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage)
But by coming gov2 and transferring the Kusama referendums to it, I cannot track the referendums through previous methods. How can i use these methods in gov2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still query all the democracy storage to get all the referendums.

You can get some indexes with:

```js
    /* The next free referendum index */
    const nextFreeIndex = await api.query.democracy.referendumCount();
    /* The lowest referendum index representing an unbaked referendum */
    const lowestUnbaked = await api.query.democracy.lowestUnbaked();
```

And with this index get a specific referendum:

```js
    const lastReferendum = await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf(lowestUnbaked);
    console.log(lastReferendum.toHuman());
```

And to get the number of (public) proposals that have been made so far:

```js
    const proposalsCount = await api.query.democracy.publicPropCount();
    console.log(proposalsCount.toHuman());
```

With that we are getting all the information you can see in the image below (Kusama governance right now):

[image]

If you want to get all the referendums (Finished and OnGoing) you can do it with this little script:

```js
    const allEntries = await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf.entries();
        allEntries.forEach(([{ args: [id] }, referendum]) => {
            console.log(`${id}: Referendum: ${JSON.stringify(referendum.toHuman())}`);
     });
```

For more information check the [democracy docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#democracy).